# Is CSRF attack possible for API authenticating with cookie but not using forms?

Tags: cookies, csrf

I understand the mechanism of the CSRF attack with the form post, but I do not get how it is possible to send a post request from a malicious site.

Imagine I have SPA at origin `S`, Web API at origin `A`, and malicious site at origin `M`.

When SPA authenticates user against API, browser saves cookie for domain `A` in the context of `S`. And when SPA issues a request to API, CORS policy is enforced by the browser. Let it be no CORS limitations at all: any method, any header, any origin, and with credentials.

Now user opens the malicious site `M` which tries to send JS request to the API, that is to `A`. But will browser attach auth cookies in this case? There are no cookies for `A` set within `M`, only cookies set for `A` within `S`.

Comment: _"There are no cookies for A set within M, only cookies set for A within S."_ - your "within" there, does not exist. There is a cookie set for A, _period_. And the browser will sent that cookie when it makes a request to A, assuming all other conditions are fulfilled.

Comment: @CBroe if so, does it mean CORS is the only protection here, and if I want to open API for any client, then cookie auth is a no-go in this case, and I have to use bearer tokens for auth?

Comment: Depends, on what exactly "open API for any client" means. It probably can't be based on _just_ a cookie for `A` then, because if you had two different websites `X` and `Y` _both_ using that service, then one would already get a "yes, user is properly logged in" response, when the _other_ one successfully authenticated the user - and that is probably not the scenario you want.

Comment: @CBroe, I mean disabled CORS checks. Every origin is allowed.

Comment: That would make rather little sense IMHO, in the scenario you described. But yes, the browser will send the cookie value with _every_ request then (as long as it has the withCredentials flag set), no matter what the origin is.